# Use ethereum from Telegram

Tags: web3js, metamask

Is it possible somehow to use Ethereum from Telegram? They seem to support custom HTML5 apps, that means that you could possibly inject web3.js there?

Comment: if you are going to downvote provide an answer. this is a new paradigm and you can't expect people to "know" the answers. you are doing harm to the community.

Comment: I think the issue with your question is that it doesn't have an straight answer. Most important chat apps are not programmable or have very limited extensibility, and build a service on top of a closed third party api can be a maintenance nightmare. So the best thing you can do is to create you own chat app, ie [Status](https://status.im/) project that provides an ethereum client with a message service included.

Comment: well Telegram is and you can develop HTML5 apps on it and I am asking if you can inject web3.js. But ofc on SO you get downvotes when people just don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [Infura](https://infura.io/) to provide your application access to the Ethereum blockchain. This is the same back end Ethereum provider that MetaMask uses.

Infura provides a JSON-RPC:

```
$ curl -X POST
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
--data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_blockNumber",
"params": []}'
"https://mainnet.infura.io/YOUR-API-KEY"
```

And even a REST like API:

```
https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_blockNumber?token=YOUR-API-KEY
```